# How to upsize volume of Terraformed EKS node

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

We have been using Terraform for almost a year now to manage all kinds of resources on AWS from bastion hosts to VPCs, RDS and also EKS.

We are sometimes really baffled by the EKS module. It could however be due to lack of understanding (and documentation), so here it goes:

**Problem:** Upsizing Disk (volume)

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "12.2.0"

  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.19"
  subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

  #...

  node_groups = {
    first = {
      desired_capacity = 1
      max_capacity     = 5
      min_capacity     = 1

      instance_type = "m5.large"
    }
  }
```

I thought the default value for this (dev) k8s cluster's node can easily be the default 20GBs but it's filling up fast so I know want to change `disk_size` to let's say 40GBs.

=> I thought I could just add something like `disk_size=40` and done.

`terraform plan` tells me I need to replace the node. This is a 1 node cluster, so not good. And even if it were I don't want to e.g. drain nodes. That's why I thought we are using managed k8s like EKS.

**Expected behaviour:** since these are elastic volumes I should be able to upsize but not downsize, why is that not possible? I can def. do so from the AWS UI.

Sure with a slightly scary warning:

*Are you sure that you want to modify volume vol-xx?
It may take some time for performance changes to take full effect.
You may need to extend the OS file system on the volume to use any newly-allocated space*

But I can work with the provided docs on that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console

Any guidelines on how to up the storage? If I do so with the UI but don't touch Terraform then my EKS state will be nuked/out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the terraform-aws-eks terraform module you are actually following the "ephemeral nodes" paradigm, because for both ways of creating instances ([self-managed workers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/worker.html) or [managed node groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html)) the module is creating Autoscaling Groups that create EC2 instances out of a Launch Template.

ASG and Launch Templates are specifically designed so that you don't care anymore about specific nodes, and rather you just care about the number of nodes. This means that for updating the nodes, you just replace them with new ones, which will use the new updated launch template (with more GBs for example, or with a new updated AMI, or a new instance type).

This is called "rolling updates", and it can be done manually (adding new instances, then draining the node, then deleting the old node), with scripts (see: eks-rolling-update in github by Hellofresh), or it can be done automagically if you use the AWS managed nodes (the ones you are actually using when specifying "node_groups", that is why if you add more GB, it will replace the node automatically when you run apply).

And this paradigm is the most common when operating Kubernetes in the cloud (and also very common on-premise datacenters when using virtualization).

**Option 1) Self Managed Workers**

With self managed nodes, when you change a parameter like disk_size or instance_type, it will change the Launch Template. It will update the $latest version tag, which is commonly where the ASG is pointing to (although can be changed). This means that old instances will not see any change, but new ones will have the updated configuration.

If you want to change the existing instances, you actually want to replace them with new ones. That is what this ephemeral nodes paradigm is.

One by one you can drain the old instances while increasing the number of desired_instances on the ASG, or let the cluster autoscaler do the job. Alternatively, you can use an automated script which does this for you for each ASG: https://github.com/hellofresh/eks-rolling-update

In terraform_aws_eks module, you create self managed workers by either using worker_groups or [worker_groups_launch_template](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/examples/launch_templates/main.tf) (recommended) field

**Option 2) Managed Nodes**

Managed nodes is an EKS-specific feature. You configure them very similarly, but in reality, it is an abstraction, and AWS will create the actual underlying ASG.

You can specify a Launch Template to be used by the ASG and its version. Some config can be specified at the managed node level (i.e. AMI and instance_types) and at the Launch Template (if it wasn't specified in the former).

Any change on the node group level config, or on the Launch Template version, will trigger an automatic rolling update, which will replace all old instances.

You can [delay the rolling update](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/pull/1447) by just not pointing to the $latest version (or pointing to $default, and not updating the $default tag when changing the LT).

In terraform_aws_eks module, you create self managed workers by using the [node_groups](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/examples/managed_node_groups/main.tf) field. You can also play with these settings: create_launch_template=true and set_instance_types_on_lt=true if you want the module to create the LT for you (alternatively you can just not use it, or pass a reference to one); and to set the instance_type on such LT as specified above.

But behavior is similar to worker groups. In no case you will have your existing instances changed. You can only change them manually.

**However, there is an alternative: The manual way**

You can use the EKS module to create the control plane, but then use a regular EC2 resource in terraform (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance) to create one ore multiple (using count or for_each) instances.

If you create the instances using the aws_instance resource, then terraform will patch those instances (updated-in-place) when any change is allowed (i.e. increasing the root volue GB or the instance type; whereas changing the AMI will force a replacement).

The only tricky part, is that you need to configure the cloud-init script to make the instance join the cluster (something that is automatically done by the EKS module when using self/managed node groups).

However, it is very possible, and you can borrow the script from the module and plug it into the aws_instance's user_data field (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data)

In this case (when talking about disk_size), however, you still need to manually (either by SSH, or by running an hacky exec using terraform) to patch the XFS filesystem so it sees the increased disk space.

**Another alternative: Consider Kubernetes storage**

That said, there is also another alternative for certain use cases. If you want to increase the disk space of those instances because of one of your applications using a hostPath, then it might be the case that you can use a kubernetes built-in storage solution using the EBS CSI driver.

For example, I manage an ElasticSearch cluster in Kubernetes (and deploy it from terraform with the helm module), and it uses dynamic storage provisioning to request an EBS volume (note that performance is the same, because both root and this other volume are EBS volumes). EBS CSI driver supports volume expansion, so I can just increase this disk by changing a terraform variable.

---

To conclude, I would not recommend the aws_instance way, unless you understand it and are sure you really want it. It may make sense in certain cases, but definitely not common

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive write up! I think the "scary" part about the managed groups is that if you use e.g. TF in this case and you are in a 1 node setup it's unclear what happens to the deployed content inside. Is the "automagical" route ensuring that after nodes are drained, the new nodes contain all content? esp. in the 1 node setup it wasn't intuitive for me what happens after applying. but maybe that's because I am thinking of the manual draining as you alluded to

Comment: The magical part is nothing but the regular flow, but it is done unattended. Here you have it explained: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-update-behavior.html you can experiment with it using kubectl get pods -w -A -o wide and see how the pods are rescheduled during the update

Comment: Yeah also found this at https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/585#issuecomment-675093297 when they were discussing support of launch templates for managed node groups. This indeed seems to be the default behavior - need to give it a go

Comment: what that doc is missing as a usecase though is changing instance type or disk_size and there is no way to edit this through the console. Are you sure the pods are actually moved automatically if you change the disk_size or instance_type. This is something which you cannot change https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039596/6597361 and requires a new node group. So does AWS go the extra magic mile? Because migrating pods to a new node group is normally relatively complex as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/migrate-stack.html

Comment: Updating instance type is very possible with managed node groups if you specify the instance type in the launch template instead of at the node group level (when creating the node group for the first time). And again, if you are using managed node groups, yes, the rolling update process will create new instances, then drain and remove old ones one by one automatically. Draining means cordoning (mark as uneshedulable) and removing the pods from that node. Your apps could have a few seconds of downtime while being created on a new node unless you have more than one replica of the pods.

Comment: And that rolling update occurs on every change of the launch template. Of course, because the easiest way to increase the disk size is by replacing the node with a new one. If you don't want that you need to either use non-managed worker groups, or delay the rolling update of the managed nodes by not updating the launch template version number. After that you would need to manually update your old node and fix/expand the file system.

Comment: Updating instance type is very possible with managed node groups **if you specify the instance type in the launch template instead of at the node group level (when creating the node group for the first time)** => the if part is the important one :) As you can see above from the code the launch template is not specified. Does that mean I need to create a 2nd node group properly with a launch template and manually drain the nodes. Thus giving me the flexibility from that point onward. Or can I change the launch template now without side effects? Final question related to this :)

Comment: I am assuming your new question is now related to instance_type, not about disk size. In such case yes, instance type is a unique and the only case that works different. If you want to be able to change the instance type (and trigger a rolling update -or not- to replace the old ones with new instances of the new type), then YES, a new group is required that uses launch templates. Within the group (above: "first") you need to set create_launch_template=true and set_instance_types_on_lt=true. https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/modules/node_groups/locals.tf

Comment: In my head I was thinking disk size assuming it’s the same. Wouldn’t disk size also require the same procedure? If I change disk_size I also get a replace from terraform plan. Final final question. Marking yours as the answer - this is the definitive guide to the jungle for me!

Comment: 1) worker group: You get a plan that changes your launch template (for future instances) but old ones will not change unless you change them one by one manually
2) managed nodes: It depends, the plan will change the launch template, and if your node group is configured to use the latest LT version, it will also force a rolling update (see my explanation here on delaying rolling updates: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/pull/1447)
3) Only way to auto-change config on existing instances is by creating instances "manually" as explained in my answer (with aws_instance)

Comment: I updated the answer to better summarize all options

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, there is currently no way to resize an EKS node volume without recreating the node using Terraform.

Fortunately, there is a workaround: As you also found out, you can directly change the node size via the AWS UI or API. To update your state file afterward, you can run `terraform apply -refresh-only` to download the latest data (e.g., the increased node volume size). After that, you can change the node size in your Terraform plan to keep both plan and state in sync.

For the future, you might want to look into moving to ephemeral nodes as (at least my) experience shows that you will have unforeseeable changes to clusters and nodes from time to time. Already planning with replaceable nodes in mind will make these changes substantially easier.

Comment: QED! thank you do you have a good starting point @ ephemeral nodes?

Comment: `Ephemeral nodes` means that you no longer care about individual nodes but rather the whole resources provided by the cluster. Furthermore, nodes will be recreated from time to time. A first step in this direction is [incorporating spot nodes](https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/aws-eks-with-amazon-ec2-spot-instances-405o) in your dev/test clusters with a limited lifetime (and better prices).